# Take a screenshot from canvas with size of bigger than 20,000 pixels

Tags: c#, wpf

I need take a screenshot from a part of Canvas but because RenderTargetBitmap 
 doesn't support take a screenshot from a region first I should take a screenshot from total of the Canvas and after that crop it with CroppedBitmap.

But problem is size of the canvas is bigger than 20000px and when I use from RenderTargetBitmap to take a screenshot sometimes I have an error about out of memory.

Do you have any idea to take a screenshot just with a start point and an end point instead of take a screenshot from total of my canvas in WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render a cropped area from a UI element into a bitmap by a method like shown below.

It uses a `VisualBrush` with an appropriate [`Viewbox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.tilebrush.viewbox?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Media_TileBrush_Viewbox) to draw the crop into a `DrawingVisual`, which is subsequently drawn into a `RenderTargetBitmap`.

```
private BitmapSource RenderCrop(Visual element, Rect crop)
{
    var visualBrush = new VisualBrush
    {
        Visual = element,
        ViewboxUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute,
        Viewbox = crop,
        Stretch = Stretch.None
    };

    var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();

    using (var dc = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
    {
        dc.DrawRectangle(visualBrush, null, new Rect(0, 0, crop.Width, crop.Height));
    }

    var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)Math.Round(crop.Width), (int)Math.Round(crop.Height),
        96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);

    bitmap.Render(drawingVisual);

    return bitmap;
}
```